# Counting previous lines using information from two files in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, count, bioinformatics

I will just delve into explaining my programming problem:  I have two files; file #1 which is a gene annotation file and file #2 which is a counts by base position file (just trying to give some context to the problem).

I want to extract the "start_codon" position in the lines where there is a "+" in column 6, and go to that position in file#2.  For instance, I want to extract 954 from column number 3 in file #1 and go to row number 954 in file #2.  Then, I want to count the number of lines above line 954 that yield a count value of 70 or greater in file #2.

```
File#1

    Chromosome  exon    337 774 0.0 -   .   gene_id "A";    
    Chromosome  start_codon 954 956 0.0 +   0   gene_id "B"; 
    Chromosome  stop_codon  2502    2504    0.0 +   0   gene_id "B"; 

 File#2
 .      .
 .      . 
 942    71
 943    63
 944    88
 945    80
 946    80
 947    85
 948    86
 949    97
 950    97
 951    97
 952    104
 953    105
 954    104
 955    108
```

My final output file will be a tab-separated file of the gene_id followed by the number of lines that yield a count value of 70 or greater.  For the example files I have given the output would be as follows:

```
 Gene_id  Count_before_start_codon
 B     10
```

I want to loop through large files to produce one long output file.

Thank you, I hope this is clear. I appreciate any guidance!

Comment: To decrease coding effort, you can `grep '^+' inputfile > script.py` to only process the matching lines, and offload some work to the built-in grep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work...
The first part gets the gene information in file 1 and populates a dictionary
The second part opens file 2, checks the dictionary and produces the output.

```
D={}
with open("file1.txt","rU") as f1:
    for line in f1:
        line=line.rstrip().rsplit("\t")
        if line[6]=="+" and line[2]=="start_codon":
            D[line[3]] = line[8].rstrip('"')[9]
            keys = D.keys()

count=[]
results=[]
number = 12
with open("file2.txt","rU") as f2:
    for line in f2:
        line=line.rstrip().rsplit("\t")
        if int(line[1]) >= 70:
            count.append(line[1])
            if line[0] in D:
                results.append(D[line[0]])
                if len(count) > number:
                    results.append(str(number))
                else:
                    results.append(str(len(count)-1))
                print "\t".join(results)
                count=[]

        else:
            count=[]
```

ps. I copy pasted your example. I edited the files to be tab-delimited. So you may need to play around with the "slicing"

Comment: Thanks this is really great.  My only problem is that the output just seems to be increasing in count regardless of if the count is >70.  What I may have not been clear about is that each gene will have a different number of lines above it until the count value reaches below 70.  For instance in my example gene B should have 10 lines above it until there is a value of below 70, but gene A might have 400 lines above it until one line reaches below 70.

Comment: I edited the code. If I understood you correctly, this should do it. This code assumes that the "954" will have a value above 70...

Comment: Thanks again.  Only problem is that I am getting the error "invalid literal for int with base 10: 'position'" when I try to do int(line[1]) >= 70. Any ideas on that?  There are no blank entries in the file so I am confused as to why it is having trouble converting to int.

Comment: Nevermind @Stylize, I figured out my problem.  Thanks so much!

Comment: One follow up question, how could I manipulate the script so that it counts not just when a value falls below 70 but when a value falls below 70 OR a certain row number is reached?

Comment: add a statement testing if len(count)>= number. If true: print the number not len(count)

Comment: @C9r1y I added the test. This should do it

Comment: Thank you, although I guess I should not have said a certain row number, I meant more like I want to find whether len(count) is longer than len between two start codons (line[0]).  I am trying to add in another if statement like `if int(line[1]) and line[0] in dict:` then append the output to a new list and then compare lengths?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple and assuming file 2 is not huge, you could load file 2 into a numpy array, which lets you access any position very fast. For example, if you load it into array ar and want to search before position p, you could do:

```
numpy.sum(ar[:p]>=70)
```

which would give you the number you are looking for

Then you can go through file #1 and do the calculation on the fly. This way you only need to read each file once and it should be fast.

Comment: Yes, my problem is that the row position does not correspond with the start position at which I want to start counting.  How do I remedy this within numpy?  Thank you!

Comment: @C9r1y your question states that if File 1 says position 954 then you want to go to line 954 in File 2. That means position 954 is in line 954.

Comment: I guess I should have said go to the line beginning with the number 954 in this example.  My fault.

Comment: @C9r1y it is still only a small change: build an array filled with zeros, and then when you read (val1,val2) from file 2, set ar[val1]=val2 and it will work the same.